# Silence the package "scontents"

Tags: warnings, silence

I use the package `scontents` in one of my packages, and since some other packages may loaded `verbatim` internally, there is always a warning

```
The implementation of the 'verbatimsc' environment
(scontents) used by \typestored is not compatible with package
(scontents) 'verbatim'. Review the documentation and redefine
(scontents) the 'verbatimsc' environment.
```

I tried to use `silence` to remove this error, but it didn't work.

```
\documentclass{article}

\RequirePackage{silence}
\WarningsOff[scontents]

\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{scontents}

\begin{document}

Text in case of empty.

\end{document}
```

Is there anyway to disable this warning?

Comment: `silence` doesn't work (for `expl3` messages). Just load `verbatim` after `scontents`.

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik The thing is that `verbatim` is not loaded by me and I don't know which package loads it internally, so there seems no way to guarantee that `scontents` is loaded before `verbatim`.

Comment: Well, then the canonical way to disable an `expl3` message is `\ExplSyntaxOn \msg_redirect_name:nnn { scontents } { unsupported-verbatim } { info } \ExplSyntaxOff` (that will still write to the log; use `none` if you don't want that).  Though the warning is likely there for a reason; sweeping it under the rug isn't the recommended approach :) (unless of course you're sure it's safe).

Comment: I'd expect packages to leave messages from other packages alone: the _user_ might choose to silence them, but that's different. Redirecting your own messages is different of course.

Answer (score 2):

The warning was put for a reason (not to annoy the user :), the `verbatim` package is loaded by `tcolorbox`, which as far as I see is loaded by your package at some point.

The version 2.0 of `scontents` (available soon in TeX Live 2022) removes the incompatibility and the patch will no longer be necessary.

Two notes (aside from the topic).

1. As you have read in the comments, it is not recommended to use the `silence` package (messages are there for a reason).
2. Maybe it would be good if you document which packages are loaded in your implementation, that is quite helpful to know the order and which ones are loaded.

Regards